# Does the Stieltjes integral $ \int_{0} ^{\sqrt{\pi}} \cos(x^{2}) d(\sin (x^{2}))$ exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Does the Stieltjes integral $ \int_{0} ^{\sqrt{\pi}} \cos(x^{2}) d(\sin (x^{2}))$ exists? if it exists, find its value.

$f(x) = \cos (x^{2})$ is continuous and monotonic decreasing in $[0, \sqrt{\pi}]$. $\alpha(x) = \sin(x^{2})$ is continuous in $[0,\sqrt{\pi}]$. I want to prove that $f\in R (\alpha)$ in $[0, \sqrt{\pi}]$. Its value I have already found with the theorem that reduces it to an integral of Riemann.

Comment: Type **\sin(.)**, **\cos(.)** to get a nicer result. The same for any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f is continuous and $\alpha$ is of bounded variation since it's derivative is bounded so f is in R($\alpha$)